# Auto Fake Django Migration

Tags: python, django, migration

I need to auto fake a Django 1.9 migration. Is there a flag that can put in the migration file that will auto fake, rather than having to log onto multiple servers and run.

The migrations layout is like this

```
migtarions
    |-- 0001_initial.py
    |-- 0002.py
    |-- 0003.py
```

I know I can do ./manage.py my_app migrate 0002 --fake, but can  migration 0002 be auto faked ?  and all I need to run is ./manage.py my_app migrate

Comment: Note that Django 1.9 is end of life, and does not receive security updates. You should try to upgrade to the 1.11.x LTS release at least.

Comment: You could just delete `operations` in the `Migration` of `0002.py` and replace them with a dummy one that doesn't do anything (or just delete the file and correct the `dependencies`).

Comment: Maybe I should be a little more clearer on what I need to do. I have an existing table that's part of a third party app. I am rewriting the model with some fields changed. So 0002.py creates the new model with the meta referencing the existing table. 0003.py then does the field updates.

Comment: You need to delete the 0002.py migrations file and run the migrate command again.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing when migrating from Django's native User model to a custom one in a live project with existing migrations. I accomplished it by overriding the apply/unapply methods:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.13 on 2018-08-13 13:43
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.core.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('custom', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 255 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=255, unique=True, validators=[django.core.validators.RegexValidator('^[\\w.@+-]+$', 'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.')], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'auth_user',
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state

    def unapply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state
```

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.8+ does not auto fake migrations. You need to use the `--fake-initial` option to tell Django to fake the initial migrations.

```
./manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

You can then set `initial = True` on your `0002` migration class to tell Django that it's an initial migration.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True    
    dependencies = [('migrations', '0001_initial')]
```

See the docs on [initial migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations) for more info.